# Setting User Mode server to run at user profile login in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, automation, services

I have a server, starting automatically as a service and would like to do the aforementioned in the subject line. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?  I have opened up the properties for The service and find a LOG ON tab with 2 options: *LOCAL SYSTEM ACCOUNT* , and *THIS ACCOUNT* (other, specify).

Is this the option to configure?
Or is there another configurator?

My problem may be related to the fact that when I manually try to start VNC server, I get a pop up asking if I want VNC to make changes to my computer. Can I disable that pop up to always able to make changes?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest me the [best blue light filter for pc](https://www.stuffroots.com/blue-light-filter-for-pc/). I shifted in this new house and want to install the best modem router for Comcast.